# Can there be a UN resolution to remove a country from the UN Security Council?

Tags: international-relations, international-law, united-nations, international, unsc

Can there be a United Nations (UN) resolution to remove a country from the United Nations Security Council (UNSC)?

I am wondering if we can vote a country like France or China out of the UNSC. Is there any rule that forbid such a resolution to be drafted, or is anything possible?

Comment: Did you not know about the history of the PRC's seat?

Comment: Note that you might want to distinguish between permanent members (China, France, Russia, UK, USA) and non-permanent members (the other ten).

Comment: China is going to be hard, since they have veto power.

Comment: @Obie2.0 what is the history of PRC's seat?

Comment: @DavidRicherby the other ten :) haha

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Yes

The first and most obvious method is based on the UN charter, Article VI, which says in its entirety:

> A Member of the United Nations which has persistently violated the
>   Principles contained in the present Charter may be expelled from the
>   Organization by the General Assembly upon the recommendation of the
>   Security Council.

Obviously, if expelled from the UN, a country could no longer be a member of the Security Council.

Now, normally members of the Security Council have effective veto power, but Article 27 lists exceptions:

> Decisions of the Security Council on all other matters shall be made
>   by an affirmative vote of nine members including the concurring votes
>   of the permanent members; provided that, in decisions under Chapter
>   VI, and under paragraph 3 of Article 52, a party to a dispute shall
>   abstain from voting.

The definition of disputes under Chapter VI is quite broad, so it seems likely that a country could bring a dispute to the UN focusing on a country's membership, and that country would have to abstain from voting on the issue. It could also be argued that the "recommendation of the Security Council," unlike "the affirmative vote of nine members," makes no mention of unanimity, and thus that a simple majority would suffice. Obviously this is subject to international jurisprudence, but since I doubt a case specifically dealing with this has come up, it's a viable interpretation.

Further, since this site deals with politics, not law, we must consider that in reality a country practically *can* be removed from the UN security council regardless of the legitimacy of the legal justifications, assuming the countries that oppose its membership and especially, the other members of the Security Council, want to remove it and are sufficiently economically or militarily powerful. If the legal methods were invalid or insufficient, they would come up with some justification to declare the nation's membership invalid in the first place.

The obvious historical precedent is Taiwan, the Republic of China, which the questioner may already be aware of. It used to be a permanent member of the UN Security Council as the successor state to the unified China that existed before 1949, until China, the People's Republic of China, became wealthy enough, and its control over the mainland obvious enough, that it made more sense for them to be a member of the Security Council. Then the PRC was recognized as the legitimate government of China, and they received Taiwan's seat on the Security Council, which they retain to this day. This was the [General Assembly Resolution 2758](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_General_Assembly_Resolution_2758). Not only did Taiwan lose its seat on the Security Council, but its UN membership generally. While this transition was undoubtedly made easier by Taiwan's claims to be the government of all of China, which clearly were not practically true, I think an equivalent form of reasoning could be used for any other country.

For instance, the General Assembly might decide that their membership is *a priori* invalid due to not being a "peace-loving state," a justification that could theoretically be applied to any country, or due to not actually being a legitimate nation at all.

Comment: I can't help but wonder... If the US was removed from the UNSC, would the US find itself labeled as a terrorist state and enjoy sanctions like it has served so many times in the past. (I'm from the US, and I am quite embarrassed at my leaders actions at times. Good country, awful politicians).

Comment: @jww - The US is unlikely to be removed from its permanent seat on the UN security council until at least several other countries overtake it economically, which takes some time. Were it removed from the UN altogether, it is unlikely that it would be labeled as a "terrorist state" in any meaningful sense. In fact, to my understanding the term "terrorist state" doesn't exist in international law. States might "sponsor" terrorism. Even US president Donald Trump's unprecedented move of labeling the Iranian Revolutionary Guard a terrorist organization didn't declare Iran a "terrorist state."

Comment: In fact, I believe the term "state sponsor of terrorism" is itself a term of art of the US government, and that the UN security council or even the General Assembly aren't in the business of declaring nations to be sponsors of terrorism. The UN can impose sanctions, of course, but although sanctions against the US would be more likely if it didn't have a seat on the Security Council, they wouldn't be unprecedented. For instance, the United States has been sanctioned by Brazil (2010) and various Middle Eastern countries (1973-74).

Comment: @jww if you want the US to improve, it may help to be aware of precisely what it is and is not guilty of doing.

Comment: Really the heart of the problem was deciding which of the two entities was China. The seat was awarded to China in 1945. That was the ROC in 1945. In 1949 it became the PRC. It's the Cold War, the US sides with the ROC, the USSR with the PRC. Eventually, in 1971, everybody agrees the PRC is the legitimate representative for China. That means kicking the ROC's delegation from the seat. The US proposed to give Taiwan representation of its own, ultimately that was rejected. The ROC prefered to leave before they could be kicked out unceremoniously.

Comment: @jww: That rather would be the effective end of the UN. It is no accident that the permanent members of the security council are the major nuclear powers.

Comment: I think this answer is misleading about Taiwan. You make it sound like Taiwan was included as a permanent member and then they said, "Whoops, the PRC is way bigger." Actually it's that "China" was included, but they had a civil war and split in two. Taiwan was originally considered to be the successor state and _that's_ why it's relevant that the PRC was bigger and consolidated power.

Comment: I can clarify it a bit, but it's clear that realpolitik considerations were the main factor. Trade, anti-Communism, and so forth. What you give is the official reasoning, but effectively, Taiwan was kicked out, and China took its place. To be clear, by my consideration, before the revolution there was just China, and it was a member. Afterward, there was, de facto, Taiwan and China, two self-governing nations. Taiwan was a permanent member for some decades, and then it lost its seat and China took it.

Comment: The "obviously" statement here isn't obvious to me at all. Is there some wording somewhere that says countries expelled from the General Assembly can't be on the Security Council, or was that part just made up?

Comment: @T.E.D.  - "Made up" is a slightly uncharitable term for reaching a conclusion, I think. Do you think the document needs to explicitly say that a country has to be a member of the UN to be a member of the *UN* security council? Unless it explicitly says otherwise, I would think that would be the most logical conclusion.

Comment: But anyway, consider this, from the articles dealing witht the Security Council: "The Security Council shall consist of fifteen Members of the United Nations." I think the implication is fairly clear that being a member of the UN is a prerequisite. Do note that the UN members and Assembly are identical. Now, I suppose one could argue that the following bit, which says "[the following nations] shall be permanent members of the Security Council," overrides that. But in a hypothetical situation where there was the will and power to eject a member, which interpretation do you think they'd choose?

Comment: @Obie2.0 - There are quite a few other possible interpretations for how those rules work together (I can think of at least 3). I'll need more than "random person on the internet thinks it makes sense" to accept the proposition that none of those others are even a likely possibility.

Comment: @T.E.D. - The rules will be interpreted in the manner most favorable to the powerful, as usual. The history of Taiwan and China shows that clearly. That's why this site is about Politics, not Law. Right now that's the US, and they'd probably advocate for the interpretation most favorable to them. If in 200 years it's China, India, Nigeria, and Indonesia, they might see things differently.

Comment: @Obie2.0 - If that's the case, then the interepretation is even **more** up in the air than I was arguing. It will all come down to who is helped by which interpretation, not which is most "logical". Point made.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95175/discussion-between-obie-2-0-and-t-e-d).

Comment: "*If the US was removed from the UNSC*"... 22% of it's funding would immediately disappear (and realistically who would replace it?), and all that "stuff" and people would have to *immediately* move Somewhere Else.

Answer (score 15):

The UN Charter does not provide for any way for a country to be removed from the UNSC.  This is the case for both the permanent members (of which France and China are two, as well as the US, UK and Russia) and the non-permanent members (who serve two-year terms).

The only way that a non-permanent member can be removed mid-term, or a permanent member can be removed at all, is if an amendment is made to the UN Charter under Chapter XVIII.  This would require a 2/3 vote of the General Assembly, and all permanent members of the Security Council would have to agree with it as well.

Effectively, what this means is that a permanent member of the UNSC cannot be removed from the UNSC without its consent.

Comment: It might be easier to start a new UN without permanent members.

Comment: There's of course a trick to this, which is how Taiwan was removed.

Comment: This answer is contradicted by the other answer.  They can't both be correct.

Comment: If UK ends up balkanising itself after brexit, would England inherit the seat automatically?

Comment: @Obie2.0 That was different. China broke in two and there was a dispute about which "half" was the legitimate successor. Originally, that was declared to be Taiwan; subsequently, it became the PRC.

Comment: @mega_creamery sure, since that's where all the power and money are.

Comment: @mega_creamery It is surprising they do not demand as many seats as they have international soccer teams already ...

Answer (score 7):

Not without removing the member from the UN itself, which would still require a Security Council vote.

Disagreeing with another answer, the voting procedure quoted there does require "the concurring votes of the permanent members", so the 10 non-permanent members by themselves could not pass the resolution if any permanent member vetoed it. Given there are two electoral pacts generally (NATO and China+Russia), there will always be a veto.

The "China exception" where the PRC was recognized in place of the RoC was a change in which government was recognized, not the removal of a member. So it's of little precedental value where the goal is to remove a state altogether.

Comment: But _any_ country can effectively be removed by recognising a different government for its territory. They could withdraw recognition of US independence and subsume it in the UK’s membership. They could recognise the old French claim to England, or vice versa. They could recognise the Russian Tsars’ closest living relatives as the legitimate rulers of Russia.

Comment: Well, maybe they could. I'm of the opinion that the recognition of the PRC was completely illegal. But even accepting its legality, what benefit derives from paying to be a member of an organization willing to do that? It's not something that can be weaponized without destroying the UN.

Comment: That voting procedure requires the country involved in a dispute to abstain from the vote. I think it's probable that a dispute involving a country's membership would count.

Comment: @MikeScott that's manifestly silly.  The reason the PRC was recognized as the true ruler of China is because **they're the ones sitting in Peking, and have guns all over the country**.  IOW, while might might not make Right, it certainly does make you In Control.